# Is it possible to enable Hyper-V in Windows 10 Preview?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10-preview, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

A few weeks ago I installed latest build of Windows 10 Preview as my main system, it was upgrade from Windows 8.1.

Now lately I’ve installed Visual Studio 2013 Community to try some Windows Phone developement. The problem is I can’t launch the Windows Phone emulator because my Hyper-V feature is missing.

My virtualization is enabled in BIOS, my CPU supports it. When I enter “add Windows features” there is no Hyper-V option.

I’ve heard that for Windows 8/8.1 one should have “Pro” version to enable Hyper-V but what about W10? There aren’t different version of the preview (besides “Enterprise”) as far as I know. Is it possible that I don’t have this because I installed Preview over a “non-Pro” version of Windows 8.1?

And apparently some people run Hyper-V in Windows 10 as I’ve seen posts about some virtual machines not working after upgrade.

There is no information whatsoever about Hyper-V in Windows 10 Preview.

Comment: Is it possible in the Technical Preview, if you cannot enable it, then its not yet possible.  The technical preview is the professional version so once that feature available you will be able to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 10 (build 9926) running as a virtual, so I’m not sure if the option is not available for me because of that or because it’s not available on the current build.

However you can check to see if your options are grayed out by checking the following:

- Go to “Programs and Features.”
- On the left side panel click on “Turn Windows features on or off”
- Expand on “Hyper-V.”
- Check “Hyper-V Platform.” If it’s grayed out that means that it’s currently not available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running Windows 10 Pro Technical Preview (build 9926) x64 in a Windows 8.1 Enterprise Hyper-V virtual machine. It does show the option to install Hyper-V Management Tools and it is not greyed out. However, the Hyper-V Platform option is greyed out. But hovering over it, it states "Hyper-V cannot be installed: A hypervisor is already running."

So it appears that it is included in Windows 10 Pro, but it won't let you install a hypervisor within a running hypervisor, which makes sense.

There is also a Windows 10 Enterprise Technical Preview. You may find better support for Hyper-V in the Enterprise version, but that's purely speculation.

I also changed "Windows 10/Settings/Update and Recovery/Windows Update/Advanced/Choose How Preview Builds are Installed" from the default "Slow" setting to "Fast". To quote the description: "Getting builds faster means you'll see new things sooner. Getting builds slower could mean more solutions are available for issues."

Comment: I'm running Win 10 Pro x64 RTM. I can confirm that you can enable the management tools as WELL as the platform. I just installed Win 7 Ent in a 128GB VM.